Is every collection of discrete random variables a function of independent random variables?
Let $\Omega = \{0,1\}^n$, and let $(\Omega,2^\Omega,\mu)$ be a probability space.
Does there exist $\Omega' = \{0,1\}^N$, product probability measure $\mu' = \mu_1 \otimes \dots \otimes \mu_n$ on $(\Omega',2^{\Omega'})$, and map $f : \Omega' \rightarrow \Omega$ such that $\mu = \mu' \circ f^{-1}$?
In terms of random variables, we may reformulate this question as follows: Let $(X_1,\dots,X_n) \in \{0,1\}^n$ be a random vector (with law $\mu$). Does there exist a collection of independent Bernoulli random variables $Y_i \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p_i)$, $i= 1,\dots N$, and a measurable map $f: \{0,1\}^N \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ such that $f(Y_1,\dots,Y_N) \overset{d}{=} (X_1,\dots X_n)$? If so, is there a 'nice' form for such an $f$?
I can convince myself that there is some multivariate Gaussian $Z = (Z_1,\dots,Z_n)$ such that $\text{sign}(Z) \overset{d}{=} 2X-1$, and that there is some affine map $L$ and i.i.d. standard Gaussians $Y$ such that $Z \overset{d}{=} L(Y)$, so that $X$ is a measurable function if i.i.d Gaussians. However, this product space is infinite, and in any case I am not even sure that this is actually true. I was wondering if there is a result that says we can accomplish this with a finite, discrete, product space.

Interesting question. I think $\Omega$ might as well be any finite set, right? The question seems quite combinatorial - "given $p_1, \dotsc, p_n \in [0, 1]$ summing to $1$, must there exist some numbers $q_1, \dotsc, q_m \in [0, 1]$ such that the numbers $x_S = \prod_{i \in S} q_i \cdot \prod_{i \notin S} (1 - q_i)$ for $S \subseteq [m]$ can be partitioned into sets whose respective sums are $p_1, \dotsc, p_n$"? I already get stuck when I try to show this is true for $p_1 = p_2 = p_3 = \frac 13$, for example. Do you happen to know an example for that case?

To be clear, you aren't assuming $n = N$ here, right?

Yes, this is always possible.  One method would be to take $N = 2^n-1$, and for each $X^i = (X^i_1,X^i_2,\cdots,X^i_n) \in \Omega$ let $p_i := \mu(\{X^i\})$.  Let \begin{align*}
Y_1 &\sim \text{Bernoulli}(p_1) \\
Y_2 &\sim \text{Bernoulli}\left( \frac{p_2}{1-p_1}\right) \\
Y_3 &\sim \text{Bernoulli}\left( \frac{p_3}{(1-p_1)\left( 1-\frac{p_2}{1-p_1}\right)}\right) = \text{Bernoulli}\left( \frac{p_3}{1-p_1-p_2}\right) \\
\vdots & \\
Y_k &\sim \text{Bernoulli}\left( \frac{p_k}{1-\sum_{j=1}^k p_j}\right), k \le 2^n-1
\end{align*}
be independent.  Note that the fact that the $p_i$s sum to one ensures that $ \frac{p_k}{1-\sum_{i=1}^k p_i} \in [0,1]$ for all $k$ (minor note: if $\mu$ doesn't have full support, we interpret $\frac{0}{0}$ as $0$ in this construction).
Now, we define our function by
\begin{align*}
f(Y_1,\cdots,Y_N) &= \begin{cases} X^1 & \text{if }Y_1 = 1 \\
X^2 & \text{if }Y_1 = 0, Y_2 = 1 \\
X^3  & \text{if }Y_1 =Y_2 = 0, Y_3= 1 \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
X^{2^n-1} & \text{if } Y_1 = Y_2 = \cdots = Y_{N-1} = 0, Y_N = 1 \\
X^{2^n} & \text{if } Y_1 = Y_2 = \cdots = Y_{N-1} = Y_N = 0.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
We can directly verify $f(Y_1,\cdots,Y_N)$ has the correct law using the independence of the $Y_i$s.

A very slick proof!
